# Overlapping Field Names in mice::md.pattern

Tags: r, plot, missing-data, r-mice

Generating a graphic in R using the `mice` package using the `md.pattern` function to graph the rows and columns of a `data.frame` where there are missing data values. This function creates a plot pasted below.  The field headers are overlapping and are illegible.  I've tried expanding the parameters of the image but that doesn't change anything.
Any ideas on how I can work around this? Any insight is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```r
md.pattern(x, plot = TRUE, rotate.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Roberta, welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for your answer. I've formatted it that it's nicer to read.

Voted your answer up as it looks correct, according to the [`mice` reference doc](https://amices.org/mice/reference/md.pattern.html). Feel free to add this to your answer.